# blender how to import fbx operate by csv file

Tags: python, scripting, import

Is there any way to import fbx file using csv.

For example in my folder with fbx files  I have those files

1.cube.fbx

2.cone.fbx

3.sphere.fbx

4.plane.fbx

5.cylinder.fbx

I would like to import only this file
which one I wrote in csv file.

Comment: Don't understand the question! Please explain more fully. What does csv have to do with fbx files?

Comment: I think the user's trying to import fbx models from a list of files in csv format, sort of like a filter or selection of files

Comment: Hello, yes that's true.
I have  a hundred of model.
and I would like to import only those one I need, And csv file will be some like the filter. 

So in my folder I have all of the fbx files. 
And I would like to wrote the list the fbx files which one should be imported to blender.